# Check proxy type

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, network-programming

I'd like to determine whether the proxy at a given IP address is transparent or anonymous. Transparent proxies connect to websites with your real IP in headers like HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR or HTTP_VIA. I would like to check these proxies, but all solutions I found are developed to work on server side, to test incoming connections for proxyness. My plan is to make a web request to an example page via the proxy. How do I check the headers sent by the proxy, preferably using the WebRequest class?

EDIT: So is there some free web API that will allow me to do this? I'm not keen on setting up a script on my own small server that will be bombarded with requests.

Comment: If you want anyone that hasn't answered reading your questions, it's probably not a good idea to close it and change it. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is technically impossible since the client only sees what the proxy returns back to the client - the proxy can do whatever it wants when communicating with the target server and transform your request and the answer from the server anyway it wants...

To really know what the proxy does you NEED see what the server gets and sends back without any interference from the proxy...

Answer (score 1):

Simply you don't need that headers. I could check transparency of a proxy by sending request to any get-my-IP site, if it returns my IP then it is transparent. If not then the proxy is anonymous. So steps are:

1. send request to any get-my-IP site without proxies
2. extract the IP from response as my local IP address
3. send new request to any get-my-IP site with the proxy
4. extract the IP from response and compare it with my local IP (step 2)
5. `if(LocalIp==ProxyIp)` then the proxy is transparent else it is anonymous

Answer (score 0):

The reason all solutions are server side is that the headers you're talking about are only passed *from the proxy to the server* and never back to the client again in the response.

In other words, if you plan to check for HTTP headers in the request from the proxy to the server, you either need to check them server side (as the solutions you found do) or actively pass them right back in the response to the client to check.

Either way, you can't just make a request to a random page and check the headers the server gets, the server needs to be involved in some way.